# Jenkins service running and access jenkins through browser

Tags: jenkins

I have installed jenkins on centos. Tried to install Jenkins , also installed Java - openjdk version "11.0.19" 2023-04-18 LTS. but i am unable to restart jenkins service and also jenkins status shows failed.
Tried to check the jenkins.log file but couldn't find the log file.
Please find the attached error messages when tried to start and check the jenkins status.
even restarting jenkins yields error message.
There is no issues with firewall and network.
Kindly Help me with starting jenkins service and accessing jenkins through browser

I tried restarting jenkins service multiple times, no go and tried to find jenkins.log file but couldn't able to find

Comment: I'm afraid I don't see the error logs you mentioned.

Comment: can you please give us error logs.